# CascadeType.All not updating other entity in a relation

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.2, one-to-one

I have 2 entities with One-to-One relation Employer and EmployerDetails as given below:

**Employers**

```
public class Employers {
     @Id //signifies the primary key
     @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employerDetials_id")
    private EmployerDetails employerDetails;
}
```

**EmployerDetails**

```
public class EmployerDetails {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "employerDetails_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long employerDetails_id;

    private Long address;

}
```

As far as I know on updating `Employer`, `EmployerDetails` should be updated because of `cascadeType.All`

Update Employer code

```
 public void update(Long id) {

        this.setId(id);
        JPA.em().merge(this);
    }
```

My problem is that when I call the above function what happens

```
insert into EmployerDetails(id,address) values(1,"newaddress");   then
update Employer set employerDetails_id=1;
```

What I understood about `cascadeType.All` is that it does`(PERSIST,MERGE,REMOVE,DELETE etc)` so the `EmployerDetails` should be updated not inserted on updating `Employer`(Correct me If I am wrong).

So everytime I update `Employer` a new row is created in `EmployerDetails` and `Employer` is updated with that new `employerDetails_id` without affecting(not deleted not updated) previous rows in `EmployedDetails`.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @hragheb this is my actual code .I have removed other fields and posted only the required code

Comment: what is the PK of Employers..Where update() method resides?

Comment: @hragheb sorry forget to put id in employer in the above code ,update my question

Comment: downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a PK which is set to be auto generated. Whatever value you set in the PK will be ignored and the persistence provider will create a new one.

Comment: I am setting id of Employer entity and its updated the problem is with EmployerDetails entity it gets inserted when I update Employer entity

Comment: Because the id column is insertable and updatable by default. However, the logic still means that it's a new entity and so any entity with relation to Employer are considered new.

Comment: you can try to set the FK in EmployerDetails with the new id value  of Employer and check if that will update rather than insert new Employer details

Comment: so you are saying `this.setid(id)` doesnt make a difference so if I dont do this how will I merger my old row with new one(I have checked play sample projects  they use the same method) and I want my relation to be unidirectional so i dont have any employer colm in employerDetails

Comment: I mean to do this                                                                                                              public void update(Long id) {
        this.getEmployerDetails().setId(id);
        this.setId(id);
        JPA.em().merge(this);
    }

Comment: I dint get you setting same id on employer.id and employer.employerDetails.id